# Android.jar on a server

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on a client-server app for android and I'm wondering if it is ok to use the Android.jar library for the server component of my application. Does anyone understand the legalities and technicalities surrounding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Android.jar is full of empty methods that throw Stub exceptions when you try to run off device. If you're doing this for unit tests or just something to build against then you can use something like [mockito](http://mockito.org/) to either suppress the implementations or mock the return data.  Since you are using the jar and not modifying the source, you shouldn't have any problems legally.

Comment: this isn't for unit tests or anything like that (although that is a good idea) i actually wanted to use it because i was intending to serialize some objects and send them back and forth between the server and the phone. Looks like i'll be going back to the drawing board though, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a real build of android.jar?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are trying to do this for serialization then use common serialization format: JSON, protocol buffers, etc..

You could try to port Android native `Parcel` but it relies on native code, which would make it almost-impossible to port. For example [`writeInt(..)`](http://www.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java&l=391).